# Reading os.OpenFile in Golang while still being written?

Tags: go

I have code that is writing to a logfile while executing a system command. E.g.

```golang
    logfile, err := os.OpenFile(THIS_LOG_FILE, os.O_APPEND|os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREATE, 0600)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    cmd.Stderr = logfile
    cmd.Stdout = logfile

    go func() {
        err := cmd.Run()
        if err != nil {
            // WANT TO LOG ERROR HERE
        }
    }()
```

At the "// WANT TO LOG" line, I'd like to output the content to the standard logger, in addition to the previously assigned logfile destination. Is there a way to capture this in memory? Or should I just write everything to an in-memory buffer and flush at the end?

To clarify, in capturing the output of the command in memory, I can parse it and take action in the running program (handling errors/etc). When I write to the log file, that information is lost.

My issue is that, theoretically, I *could* read that back in from the file I just wrote, but that seems wasteful (and prone to failure if the command failed).

Comment: Do you want to write the content of stderr/stdout from command execution to a file ?

Comment: The writing to a file is working properly when it works. But when it doesn't, I want to write the stdout and stderr to the logger (because we collect that elsewhere).

Comment: You can refer the code that I posted below. If you want to log the error, you can replace the `log.Fatalln` by `f.Write([]byte("your-message"))` to the log file.

Comment: I do see this - but when I execute, and the item fails (at cmd.Wait()) with error 137 and I can't seem to read the stderr.

Comment: The `io.Copy` uses a buffer (32kB) while copying by default. Is there any security policies related to shell execution in your environment ?

Comment: Sorry, wrote some clarification. The issue isn't security or any restriction, it's more something like Run Command -> Command has error -> Parse the error in the running program. If I write all that information to the file, then the only place I can get it is back from the file (rather than as an object in memory).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to write the content of stdout/stderror to a file while executing a shell command.

Since stdout and stderror are implemented the ReadCloser interface, you can merge them by `io.MultiReader` and perform `io.Copy` from source to destination.

The following snippet implements the pipeline

```golang
package main

import (
    "io"
    "log"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    // prepare the command
    cmd := exec.Command("your-shell-command.sh")

    // get the stdout and stderr stream
    erc, err := cmd.StderrPipe()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln("Failed to get stderr reader: ", err)
    }
    orc, err := cmd.StdoutPipe()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln("Failed to get stdout reader: ", err)
    }

    // combine stdout and stderror ReadCloser
    rc := io.MultiReader(erc, orc)

    // Prepare the writer
    f, err := os.Create("output.log")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln("Failed to create file")
    }
    defer f.Close()
    // Command.Start starts a new go routine
    if err := cmd.Start(); err != nil {
        log.Println("Failed to start the command")
    }

    // add the TeeReader.
    var buf bytes.Buffer 
    tr := io.TeeReader(rc, &buf) 
    if _, err := io.Copy(f, tr); err != nil { 
        logger.Fatalf("Failed to stream to file: %s", err) 
    }


    if err := cmd.Wait(); err != nil {
        log.Println("Failed to wait the command to execute: ", err)
    }
}
```

Comment: FWIW, I ended up using teereader, to write to both a buffer and the file.  var bufferRead bytes.Buffer
 teereader := io.TeeReader(rc, &bufferRead)
 if _, err := io.Copy(f, teereader); err != nil {
  logger.Fatalf("Failed to stream to file: %s", err)
 }

If you add this in, i'll accept it as an answer - otherwise, i'll add my own.